# Auto Moving Div around the web page on load event. And need to stop this moving when mouse over...?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to move a `div` around the web page using `onload` event in javascript. And need to stop this movement when `mouse over` event has been called?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var wid=1002;

  var rmax = wid2;
  var tmr  = 10;

  var intg = 2;
  var dir  = 2;

  function moveIt() {
    obj = document.getElementById("d1").style;
    curr = parseInt(obj.left);
    if (curr > rmax) {
      dir = -dir;
    }
    obj.left = curr + dir + "px";
    if ((curr == 0) && (dir < 0)) {
      dir = -dir;
    }
    timer=setTimeout("moveIt()", intg*tmr);
  }

  function init() 
  {
    setTimeout("moveIt()", intg*tmr);
  }

  function stoper() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
  }

  function hideDiv() {
   $(".floatMainContainer").hide();
   $(".floatThankyouContainer").show();
  }
</script>
<body onLoad="init()">
  <div id="d1" style="border:px solid black; top: 2%; left: 0px; z-index:999999; position:absolute; width:262px; height:6px; background-color:none;" onMouseOver="stoper()"   onmouseout="moveIt(),10000" >
    <div class="floatMainContainer"  >
      <span class="close">
        <span>Close</span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've reformattted your code so that it should be visible please use the preview window in order to check that your post looks like you expect it to.

Comment: Just as a comment on your code your <script> tag should be in your <head>. and `setTimeOut` can take a function as well as a string so if you call `setTimeout(moveIt, intg*tmr);` then it will still work and be a bit more robust.

Comment: @Saint Gerbil, if you add the brackets like that it will execute the function when you get to that part of the script. You need to remove the brackets to have the function called only on timeout: setTimeout(moveIt, intg*tmr);

Comment: @Alex quite right, sorry, I've corrected now.

Comment: Saint Gerbil: where is preview window in this website?

Comment: HI, Where is reformatted code?

Comment: When you ask the question the preview is under the the entry text box and the reformatted code appears as the question now.

Answer (score 1):

well asuming you tagged this post with jquery, I suppose you use it.

On Load event in jQuery looks like this:

```
$(function(){ <!-- here you can start moving around your div's as crazy -->   });
```

To stop them moving (asuming you used jQuery animate to move them) just go:

```
$(yourDivsClass).mouseover(function(){ $(this).stop(); }
```